# Installing my projects apk fail on real device (android 10)

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk, android-10.0

I'm trying to install my projects apk file on my phone but it fails with an error - Cannot open file.

- Install apks from unknown source is **turned on**.
- The app I'm using (Total commander and Dropbox) **has permission to install** apps.
- Play protect is **turned off**.

Apk installs just fine on the emulator.

Phone:

- Samsung S10+ with Android 10
- Pixel 2xl with Android 10

I've found one suggestion to clean Google Play cache but that didn't help.

What could be causing this? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a few days of googling and trying different things I've finally found how to do this.

This happens because the app installer on Android 10 was updated and cannot access files on /storage/emulated/0 any more.

App installer accepts only content:links now.

Apps like Total Commander and Dropbox use real directories like /storage/emulared/0 and pass "file:" links to the app installer. That's why it doesn't work.

The solution was to install beta version of Total Commander now also sends "content:" urls.
It can be found here: https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander

For more details see here - https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=54040